# How to catch an error that is being reported on information stream?

Tags: powershell

I am using `Weird-Cmd` that has been written by someone else. This command searches the database for `things` and accepts certain parameters for its `-Filter`.

If I pass a bogus filter parameter, it returns a message telling me there's no such filter parameter.

That message is reported on Information stream (6). How do I invoke this cmdlet inside a try/catch and catch this error that is being reported on Information stream.

I tried redirecting the stream but it turned out PowerShell doesn't redirect except to Output/Success.

I do not have access to `Weird-Cmd` so I can't change it. I am limited to PowerShell 5.1.

Here is the message I get:

```
System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException: Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": ""BogusProp" is not a recognized filterable property. Valid property names are: Prop1, Prop2,...."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `Weird-Cmd` is a *cmdlet* or an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) function or script, use the [common `-InformationVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-informationvariable) to capture the information stream's output:

```bash
try {
  Weird-Cmd -InformationVariable inf # Note: NO "$" before "inf"
  if ($inf) { throw $inf }
} catch {
  # ... handle the exception.
}
```

Otherwise - which includes invoking the `Weird-Cmd` via a *script block* (`{ ... }`), use redirection `6>` to redirect the information stream to a *temporary file*:

```bash
try {
  Weird-Cmd 6>($tempFile = New-TemporaryFile)
  $inf = (Get-Content -ErrorAction Ignore -Raw $tempFile)
  $tempFile | Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore
  if ($inf) { throw $inf }
} catch {
  # ... handle the exception.
}
```

Note: If you simply want to relay the information-stream content as a  *non-terminating error*, use the [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error) cmdlet, either *instead* of [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) with [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) or from inside the `catch` block:

```bash
Write-Error $inf
```

---

[zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out that there's an *in-memory alternative* to `6>$someFile`, namely to *merge* the information stream (`6`) into the *success* output stream (`1`) with `6>&1`, and to *filter* out information-stream output objects by their *type*, [`System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord) - this assumes that `Weird-Cmd` does *not* report a *terminating* error:

```bash
$inf = Weird-Cmd 6>&1 |
       Where-Object { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord] }
```

That said, it would be nice to have a way to *directly* capture a specific stream's output *in a variable* rather than having to use a file, along the lines of: `6>variable:inf`

This potential future enhancement is the subject of [GitHub issue #4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332).

Comment: For your first approach, the message still shows. Is there a way to redirect it to be the error message? If not, and only if not, can I suppress it?

Comment: @jsnoobie, that implies that `Weird-Cmd` is _not_ a cmdlet or advanced function/script. The 2nd approach, via  a temporary file, should work in that case (assuming that it is truly stream `6`, the information stream, through which the error is reported). Also see my update re using `Write-Error` as an an alternative to `throw` and `try`/ `catch`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. In your first approach, the message still shows, and the catch block is also executed. That's why I'd like to make the message as an error message. Regarding the last approach, no.  I would like to do certain things when it fails (counting number of retries.)

Comment: @jsnoobie, if the `catch` block is executed, the implication is that  a _terminating_ error is reported by `Weird-Cmd`: you can use `$_` inside the `catch` block to examine it - but `$inf` won't be populated then.

Comment: @jsnoobie, you may also use `Write-Error` from inside a `catch` block (answer updated).

Comment: For the 1st approach, if the `Weird-Cmd` actually work, it still throws.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't, @jsnoobie, but if you can come up with a [mcve], I encourage you to ask a _new_ question.

Comment: Can we chat here on StackOverflow?

Comment: Yes, we can: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245708/room-for-mklement0-and-jsnoobie (I prepended `chat.` to the URL of your SO profile and choose to create a chat).

Comment: @zett42 I updated my post regarding how I am executing it. Sometimes `Weird-Cmd` work. And when it does, there is a returned object that I get back. I want to be able to catch it when it does NOT work.

Comment: @zett42, my aim was to focus on _directly_ capturing the information-stream content only, but you're right: what you're proposing allows for an _in-memory_ solution. Please see my update, including the link to the GitHub issue that asks for a general direct, in-memory solution.